# Can't connect to remote database with JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a database on external server with Cpanel. I've made database and all I know is that this is database adress: server: pgsql1.superhost.pl

I tried to connect like this:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:postgresql://sql1.superhost.pl:5432/database_name",
    "user_name", "password");
```

I tried without port, I tried everything, but I'm still getting error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:233)
....
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: sql1.superhost.pl
```

Comment: `pgsql1.superhost.pl` vs. `sql1.superhost.pl`

Comment: the host sql1.superhost.pl is not being resolved..

Comment: Thank you, now it gives me another error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:pgsql1.superhost.pl://sql1.superhost.pl/database_name

Comment: Finally made it: jdbc:postgresql://pgsql1.superhost.pl/database_name Thank you!

Comment: @RichardK since it is solved, either remove the question or post an answer and accept it.